# Pyparsing : Determine which one of multiple ORed parsers actually succeeded

Tags: pyparsing

I am using something like:

```
parser = parser1 ^ parser2 ^ parser3
```

and then

```
result = parser.parseString(line)
```

Is there an easy built-in method to determine which of the 3 OR'ed parsers succeeded?

Answer (score 1):

Give them results names:

```
parser = parser1("p1") ^ parser2("p2") ^ parser3("p3")
```

Then after parsing:

```
if result.p1:
    # parser1 was matched
elif result.p2:
    # parser2 was matched
elif result.p3:
    # parser3 was matched
else:
    # no parser matched, or a parser matched with empty contents
```

Also, please consider using '|' operator instead of '^', if there is no ambiguity across the 3 parsers. '|' will stop trying alternatives after the first match, where '^' will try them all and then pick the longest match.